# Beamer - text side by side

Tags: beamer

I'd like to typeset two columns of items side-by-side using beamer.

I understand that the columns environment can do the trick - but I'd like items to align horizontally - which does not work if the opposing items don't correspond line-by-line.

I know I could solve this by some tabular hacking, but placing \item inside \tabular is not trivial.

Any elegant solutions?

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `columns` environment for every pair of items.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{columns}[t,onlytextwidth]
\column{.5\textwidth}
\begin{itemize}
\item First
\end{itemize}
\column{.5\textwidth}
\begin{itemize}
\item This a longer item which will break alignment
\end{itemize}
\end{columns}
\begin{columns}[t,onlytextwidth]
\column{.5\textwidth}
\begin{itemize}
\item Second 
\end{itemize}
\column{.5\textwidth}
\begin{itemize}
\item Every column environment starts alignment again
\end{itemize}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Like, why didn't I think of that? This is so obvious.

I did manage a solution,  which works and does what I want, but I'm not going to post it since nobody should use it ever :D

Thank you!!!